# Casting to one class and calling function from sibling class?

Tags: c++, casting

I'm getting a pointer to a base class (which is actually a pointer to some derived class). Then I want to call a function on that derived class, but I don't know which one it is.

```
class Base
{

};

class DerivedOne : public Base
{
    public:
        void functionA()
        {   int x = 0;  }
};

class DerivedTwo : public Base
{
    public:
        void functionA()
        {   int x = 0;  }
};

int main()
{   
    Base* derivedTwoPtr = new DerivedTwo();

    reinterpret_cast<DerivedOne*>(derivedTwoPtr)->functionA(); 

    return 0;
}
```

This works as I want, but I have to say it looks rather dodgy. Is it defined behavior? If not, is there a legal way to dynamically resolve this?

Comment: You already got the answers on how to do what you want; to answer the other part of your question, no, it's entirely undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey, don't do that. That's what virtual methods are for.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void functionA()=0;

};

class DerivedOne : public Base
{
    public:
        virtual void functionA()
        {       int x = 0;      }
};

class DerivedTwo : public Base
{
    public:
        virtual void functionA()
        {       int x = 0;      }
};

int main()
{   
    Base* derivedTwoPtr = new DerivedTwo();

    derivedTwoPtr->functionA(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use virtual functions. That's what they are intended for. Your base class should look like

```
class Base
{
    virtual void functionA() = 0;
};
```

where the `= 0` bit is optional. If present the virtual function is known as a pure virtual function and enforces each subclass of `Base` to implement the function.

Now if you call `functionA` through a `Base` pointer you will get the method appropriate to whichever subclass the pointer really points to.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a legal way to dynamically
>   resolve this?

`dynamic_cast` can be used to cast to a specific derived class and invoke derived class methods. But in your case the best would be to provide a virtual method in Base class and provide different implementation for the virtual method in derived classes.

Comment: dynamic_cast won't work properly unless there's virtual method in base class.

Answer (score 1):

You basically answered your own question here:

> **Cast**ing to one class and calling
>   function from sibling class?
>
> This works as I want, but I have to
>   say it looks rather dodgy. Is it
>   defined behavior? If not, is there a
>   legal way to **dynamic**ally resolve this?

In short:

```
if (DerivedOne* one=dynamic_cast<DerivedOne*>(BasePtr))
  one->functionA();
else if (DerivedTwo* two=dynamic_cast<DerivedTwo*>(BasePtr))
  two->functionA();
```

But yeah, like vava said, don't do that.

Comment: the same deal, dynamic_cast doesn't work without presence of at least one virtual method in base class.