# Access methods of subclass from an instance casted to a pointer to base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have two classes `A` and `B` which derive from the same base class `Base`.
I am defining in main a vector `Base *` and I use it for storing elements both of `A` and `B`.
Using a reinterpret_cast I am able to call methods of their real class.
Is this code safe? Is there a better/standard way of doing that?

The two classes in the real code share most of the methods from the base class but the `A` possesses some methods not shared with `Base` or `B` and the same for `B`, so virtual is not an option.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
};

class A : public Base {
public:
    void print_from_A() {
        std::cout << "hello from A\n";
    }
};

class B : public Base {
public:
    int number;
    void read_from_B() {
        std::cin >> number;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<Base*> v;
    v.push_back(new A());
    v.push_back(new B());

    (reinterpret_cast<A *>(v[0]))->print_from_A();
    (reinterpret_cast<B *>(v[1]))->read_from_B();

    for(auto && e: v) {
        delete e;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

It seems that using `reinterpret_cast` is undefined behaviour: [Casting to one class and calling function from sibling class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518555/casting-to-one-class-and-calling-function-from-sibling-class)

It also seems that the correct way is using a `static_cast`: [Can I get polymorphic behavior without using virtual functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818277/can-i-get-polymorphic-behavior-without-using-virtual-functions)

Is this the answer?

Comment: Add a virtual destructor to `Base`, do downcasting using `dynamic_cast`, try not to do downcasting.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better/standard way of doing that?

1. It is better to use a `virtual` member function.
2. If you are not able to use a `virtual` member function, perform a `dynamic_cast`, check the status of the cast, and call the member function only if the cast succeeds.

Please note that the base class needs to have a `virtual` member function for `dynamic_cast` to work. In such cases, it is is recommended to make at least the destructor a `virtual` member function.

Here's an updated version of your program using `virtual` member functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base {
   public:
      virtual ~Base() {}
      virtual void print() const = 0;
      virtual void read() = 0;
};

class A : public Base {
public:
    virtual void print() const {
        std::cout << "hello from A\n";
    }
   virtual void read() 
   {
      // Nothing to do.
   }
};

class B : public Base {
public:
    int number;
    virtual void print() const {
        std::cout << "hello from B, " << number << "\n";
    }
    virtual void read() {
        std::cin >> number;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<Base*> v;
    v.push_back(new A());
    v.push_back(new B());

    v[0]->read();
    v[0]->print();
    v[1]->read();
    v[1]->print();

    for(auto && e: v) {
        delete e;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using a `dynamic_cast` I get the error 'Base' is not polymorphic

Comment: @Nisba, the base class needs to have a `virtual` member function for `dynamic_cast` to work. In such cases, it is is recommended to make at least the destructor a `virtual` member function.

Comment: It works great! Bonus question: will it work also with smart pointers?

Comment: I found that there is a standard way to do this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast

Comment: @Nisba, yes it will work with smart pointers, as you already figured it out.